# Printing from Java, Changing the fonts of the string to be printed

Tags: java, printing

I have a java code which prints a paragraph on the paper, I want to change the font of the string.

```
l_print_data = formatPrintDataNewFormat(l_print_data_format, l_arr, i+1,p_request.passwordType);    //formatPrintDataNew(l_print_data_format, l_arr);formatPrintData(l_print_data_format, l_arr);  version 1.7 change by Yogeshwar
                InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(l_print_data.getBytes("UTF-8"));
                PrintRequestAttributeSet attributes = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();
                DocFlavor flavor =  DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
                DocPrintJob job = printer_service.createPrintJob();
                Doc doc= new SimpleDoc(is, flavor, null);
                PrintJobWatcher pjDone = new PrintJobWatcher(job);
                job.print(doc, attributes);
                pjDone.waitForDone();
                is.close();
```

l_print_data is a String, I want to change font of the same while on paper to a particularly different type. How do I achieve that ? kindly please help.

Comment: I am still stuck, looks like not many in the community here have had this sort of problem before.

Comment: NSAttributedString is for iOS/OSX. Are you sure you tagged correctly?

Comment: i didn't knew it, removing it.